# Datastore datetimeproperty iterable?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, datetime, google-cloud-datastore

I have model

```
class info(db.Model):
    user = db.UserProperty()
    last_update_date = db.DateTimeProperty()
```

I need to retrieve `last_update_date` for specific user. It is working good, i can retrieve this value, i can even pass it to another variable

```
if results:
    for result in results:            
        data = result.last_update_date
```

Problem lies when i try to assign it to

```
feed_uri = contacts.GetFeedUri()
feed_query = gdata.contacts.service.ContactsQuery(feed_uri) 
feed_query.updated_min = data
```

This is done outside any loops so i do not see why it says that datetime is not iterable.
Error message i receive is

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\ext\webapp__init__.py", line 507, in **call**
>       handler.get(*groups)
>     File "C:\Users\mklich\workspace\google_contacts_webapp\src\contacts-list.py", line 266, in get
>       listc = checkUserPrivateContacts(user)
>     File "C:\Users\mklich\workspace\google_contacts_webapp\src\contacts-list.py", line 189, in checkUserPrivateContacts
>       feed = contacts.GetContactsFeed(feed_query.ToUri())
>     File "C:\Users\mklich\workspace\google_contacts_webapp\src\gdata\service.py", line 1718, in ToUri
>       return atom.service.BuildUri(q_feed, self)
>     File "C:\Users\mklich\workspace\google_contacts_webapp\src\atom\service.py", line 584, in BuildUri
>       parameter_list = DictionaryToParamList(url_params, escape_params)
>     File "C:\Users\mklich\workspace\google_contacts_webapp\src\atom\service.py", line 551, in DictionaryToParamList
>       for param, value in (url_parameters or {}).items()]
>     File "C:\Python25\lib\urllib.py", line 1210, in quote_plus
>       if ' ' in s:
>   TypeError: argument of type 'datetime.datetime' is not iterable

Am i doing something wrong or is it a bug?
Thank you for responses.

Comment: You haven't included the actual code that's causing the exception in your question, nor the code that generates the args passed to it. We need that to be able to diagnose anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example from [the contacts API documentation](http://code.google.com/apis/contacts/docs/1.0/developers_guide_python.html):

```
updated_min = raw_input('Enter updated min (example: 2007-03-16T00:00:00): ')
query = gdata.contacts.service.ContactsQuery()
query.updated_min = updated_min
```

I think the `updated_min` property takes a string, not a `datetime` object.